# Transaction isolation level listed as long lived queries in PG

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

As you can see with the following screencap

[image: screen shot 2018-04-11 at 10 41 26]

pghero accounts those `SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;` as long lived requests.

I'm fairly new to the `pg` world so I don't know if this not supposed to be the case, or just if `pghero` is counting those as long lived requests when they shouldn't.

I'm sorry if the question is not super obvious but basically:
- Is this a bug in pghero2 ?
- Is Sequelize (the nodejs ORM I use) doing something wrong when setting those configs and not releasing them?

Answer (score 2):

That's not a bug; the output is correct.

Please note that the sessions are not reported as “active”, but as “idle in transaction”.

That is correct, because the last command that ran in the sessions is

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
```

which will start a transaction.

If this is just a test system, that is no problem, but on a productive system you shouldn't keep transactions open for any longer amount of time. It may lead to locks blocking concurrent sessions, and it keeps autovacuum from doing ts job.

Close the transactions with `COMMIT` or ROLLBACK`.